# How to understand if I'm in SolrCloud mode or not?

Tags: solr, solrcloud

How can I understand, from a custom component (e.g. `SearchComponent`, `ResponseWriter`) if I am running in `SolrCloud` mode or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the answer (from DistributedUpdateProcessor):

```
coreDescriptor.getCoreContainer().isZooKeeperAware();
```